# Expected value problem with two dice

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, expected-value

I have two fair dice, one blue and one red. The blue one is thrown and we note the number it rolled. The red one is then thrown as many as the blue dice's noted number.

So for example, the blue one rolls 3 and then I roll the red dice 3 times and get $3,1,4,5$ in general. I have been trying to find a discrete probability space $(\Omega ,\mathbb{P})$ as well as the expected value $\mathbb{E}[BR_1....R_B]$ where $B$ represents the number the blue dice rolled and $R_1,....R_B$ the numbers rolled by the first...and $B$-th throw of the red dice.
I'm struggling with an understandable notation for the sample space $\Omega$ even though I understand the principle behind it. With blue rolling $1$ I only have $6$ possibilites giving $6$ samples....with blue rolling $2$ I have $36$ samples. So wouldn't the sample space be of the form {$ B,R_1,....,R_B$} whereas $R_1,....,R_B \in$ {$1,...,6$} and $\mathbb{P} = 1/6^B$?

With that said wouldn't the expected value be $\frac{1}{6} + (2 \times \frac{1}{6^2})+.....+(B\times \frac{1}{6^B})?$

Comment: expected value of what thing exactly? There $BR_1\ldots R_B$, is a product?

Comment: I think it's the product. I see the mistake now, will correct the expected value in the question

Comment: I tried to calculate it thinking it was the expected value of a specific roll. The expected value of the product is something I'm not sure of.

Comment: It is unclear as you left it what the "expected value" is to be applied to.  It makes sense to form a probability space with a finite number of outcomes, corresponding to the rolls of dice (first the blue die and then one to six red die rolls) taken as an order pair, triple, etc. up to a septuple.  But an expected value should be a single number, and as you left things it seem you were going to clarify the Question to say take the expected value of the product of all the dice in an outcome.  I'm voting to close until the Question is edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you roll $k$ dice, the expected value of their product is $(3.5)^k$ (since the expected value of each die is $3.5$, and the dice are independent).

Let $P$ denote the product of the red dice. We compute $E[P]$ by conditioning on the value of $B$:
$$
E[P]=\sum_{k=1}^6 E[P\mid B=k]\cdot P(B=k)=\sum_{k=1}^6 (3.5)^k\cdot (1/6)
$$
This is a finite geometric series, so you can evaluate this easily.

---

In this case, visualizing the probability space is not especially helpful to the problem. However, for completeness, each element in the probability space looks like one of the ordered tuples below. Each $*$ in a tuple represents a number between $1$ and $6$.
$$
(1,*),\;(2,*,*),\;(3,*,*),\;(4,*,*,*,*),\;(5,*,*,*,*,*),\;(6,*,*,*,*,*,*)
$$
The probability of a tuple of length $k$ is $(1/6)^k$.